# Lost magnification under Mountain Lion

Tags: macos

I am missing one nice feature after moving to Mountain Lion. I was able on Lion to press <kbd>control</kbd> and  drag with two fingers to magnify an area of the screen, which is particularly helpful when working with image editors that lack this function.

Was this merely a key binding that was removed, or has the feature itself been abandoned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature is still present and you might be able to set it up again as follows according to [this Apple Support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11488?viewlocale=en_US):

> For example, if you have a trackpad and used the default settings,
>   zoom in by holding down the Control (^) key while you drag two fingers
>   up on the trackpad. Zoom out by holding down the Control key while you
>   drag two fingers down on the trackpad.

Check System Preferences => Accessibility => Zoom (under Seeing) to make sure that you have `Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom` enabled.

[image]